# accessing values inside an inner method through setters and getters in java

Tags: java

This seems like an easy problem, yet I am limited by my knowledge in java.

Consider the following code:

```
public void method1(){
    Object1 obj = new Object1(){
       @Override
       public void innerMethod(Object response){
        setList(response.list);
        // Displaying the result of the getter is for sample purposes
        System.out.println(getList().get(0).getName()); // This works and prints out the name of the first item.
       }
    };
    obj.execute(); // Suppose execute method is pre-defined and just means it'll execute the `innerMethod`.
    System.out.println(getList().get(0).getName()); // This returns null for the getList().
}
```

From what I understand about the execution at runtime, the `list` should be populated once `method1` is run since `innerMethod` is the first one written.

Please help me understand why the second accessing of `getList()` returns null and how else can I access the data from `innerMethod`.

Note as well that I'm using `getList()` in another class, and there as well it returns null.

EDIT:
Below is the full code for above scenario.

```
public void callMusicAPI(){
   Callback<SongList> callback = new Callback<SongListResponse>(){
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<SongListResponse> call, Response<SongListResponse> response) {
                   setSongListResult(response.body().getResults());
                   Log.d(TAG, "Number of Songs received: " + Songs.size()); // This works.

           Log.d(TAG, "Actual Response from API Call: " + response.raw() + "" + success + " " + getSongListResult().get(1).getTitle()+getSongListResult().get(1).getRelease_date() ); //This works.
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<SongListResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
           Log.e(TAG, throwable.toString());
       }
   };
   call.enqueue(callback);
   if(call.isExecuted()) {
       if (getSongListResult() != null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Data received in setter and getter: " + getSongListResult().get(2).getTitle() + getSongListResult().get(2).getRelease_date()); 
       } else {
           Log.e(TAG, "List is super null");
       }
   }
```

}

```
public void setSongListResult(List<Song> songs){
    this.songs = songs;
}

public List<Song> getSongListResult(){
    return this.songs;
}
```

I expect after `call.enqueue(callback)` the list would be populated however, this is not the case.

Feel free to note if this is a java problem and the setter-getter would work fine on most scenarios, or if this is specific to the response from the api call. If, so do recommend if the question needs to be changed.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? It would make it much easier to work out exactly what's going on.

Comment: It would be easier if you'd post more code. E.g. the getList() method.

Comment: this seems more of understanding Java's execution at runtime, doesn't the above suffice it?the getList is just a return statement of the List<Objects>

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question. Request to provide some insight for this. Much appreciated.

Comment: It remains unclear what the type of `call` may be, but the method name `enqueue()` certainly suggests that your expectation is incorrect.  Normally, if you "enqueue" something, you are setting it up for action to be performed on it *later*, often an indeterminate amount of time in the future.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a [mcve]. There isn't a single class declaration, and you've got calls to methods you haven't declared. Please try to work your example into code that we can literally copy, paste, compile and run - but as minimally as possible. (We shouldn't need to make a web service call to see this happening, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would much rather write a comment, but since I don't have enough reputation to do that, I'll write my input as an answer. I hope that I can be of help.

It looks to me as if there is a problem with scope. If you remove all code that is "out of reach" for the second `getList()` it looks like this

```
public void method1(){
    Object1 obj = new Object1(){}
    obj.execute(); // Suppose execute method is pre-defined and just means it'll execute the `innerMethod`.
    System.out.println(getList().get(0).getName()); // This returns null for the getList().
}
```

There seems to be nothing for `getList()` to get, so maybe that's the reason for your problem.

Comment: Hi, I posted the full code for the scenario. It's important to capture the data inside the innerMethod as that's where it can only be accessed, which is why I thought of using setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method1(){
    Object1 obj = new Object1(){
       @Override
       public void innerMethod(Object response){
        setList(response.list);
        // Displaying the result of the getter is for sample purposes
        System.out.println(getList().get(0).getName()); // This works and prints out the name of the first item.
       }
    };
    obj.execute(); // Suppose execute method is pre-defined and just means it'll execute the `innerMethod`.
    System.out.println(obj.getList().get(0).getName()); // <-- ***********
}
```

I think you're calling getList() from the wrong object.  If you don't specify the object to call the method from it's assuming this.list(), in which case you're getting uninitialized data members.